# How to iterate over (unique) combinations very fast?

Tags: python, performance, combinations

My script does the following: I have a text file with scrabble racks and their "values":

```
BYZZZZĄ -8.038175
BYZZZĄŹ -14.072675
BYZZZĄŻ -1.238175
BYZZĄŹŻ -3.588175
BZZZZZĄ -13.938175
BZZZZĄŹ -9.738175
BZZZZĄŻ -10.538175
BZZZĄŹŻ -19.072675
CCCDDĄĆ -16.088175
CCCDEĄĆ -4.288175
CCCDĄĆĘ -5.588175
CCCDFĄĆ -16.788175
CCCDGĄĆ -10.338175
```

Now I want to generate a list of *partial* racks and their values. The value of a partial rack is the weighted sum of all possible *full* racks that can be created with it. So for a 6-letter rack `CCCDDA`, it would be `(CCCDDAA*8+CCCDDAB*2+CCCDDAD*1+CCCDDAE*7)/N`, where N is the number of all racks. The multipliers are equal to the number of letters left in the bag, e.g. there are 9 A's in total, but there is already one in `CCCDDA` so we only multiply by 8.

The letter distributions are as follows (in the fourth column):

```
A   a   1   9   1
Ą   ą   5   1   1
B   b   3   2   0
C   c   2   3   0
Ć   ć   6   1   0
D   d   2   3   0
E   e   1   7   1
Ę   ę   5   1   1
F   f   5   1   0
G   g   3   2   0
H   h   3   2   0
I   i   1   8   1
J   j   3   2   0
K   k   2   3   0
L   l   2   3   0
Ł   ł   3   2   0
M   m   2   3   0
N   n   1   5   0
Ń   ń   7   1   0
O   o   1   6   1
Ó   ó   5   1   1
P   p   2   3   0
R   r   1   4   0
S   s   1   4   0
Ś   ś   5   1   0
T   t   2   3   0
U   u   3   2   1
W   w   1   4   0
Y   y   2   4   1
Z   z   1   5   0
Ź   ź   9   1   0
Ż   ż   5   1   0
blank   0   2
```

There are 11M possible racks, so calculating all partial values is time consuming. This is my current approach (also available on [github](https://github.com/alkamid/quackle/blob/2159e85b0e492093736b2645bb76455e4ad8435c/test/partialRacks.py)):

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import io
import itertools
import time

def loadAlphabet(filename):
    fil = io.open(filename, encoding="utf-8")
    lines = fil.readlines()
    letters = {}
    for line in lines:
        line = line.split()
        if line[0] == 'blank':
            letters[u'?'] = int(line[2])
        else:
            letters[u'%s' % line[0]] = int(line[3])
    fil.close()
    return letters

def adjustBag(rack, bag):
    newBag = bag.copy()
    for letter in rack:
        newBag[letter] -= 1
    return newBag

def partialValue(rackLen):

    bag = loadAlphabet("../data/alphabets/polish.quackle_alphabet")
    racks = io.open("racks%d.txt" % rackLen, encoding='utf-8').read().splitlines()
    leaveList = io.open("leavesSorted.txt", encoding='utf-8').read().splitlines()

    leaves = {}

    # create a dictionary of leave:value
    for line in leaveList:
        (lv, val) = line.split()
        leaves[lv] = float(val)

    outFile = io.open("rack%doutput.txt" % rackLen, 'w', encoding='utf-8')

    for r in racks:
        smallerBag = adjustBag(r, bag)
        bagList = []

        for letter in smallerBag:
            bagList += smallerBag[letter]*letter

        combs= itertools.combinations(bagList, 7-rackLen)
        combSet = set(combs)

        sumVals = 0.0
        i = 0.0
        avgVal = 0.0

        for elem in combSet:
            multiplier = 1.0
            for letter in elem:
                multiplier *= smallerBag[letter]

            fullrack = u''.join(sorted(r + u''.join(elem)))
            sumVals += leaves[fullrack]*multiplier
            i+= multiplier

        avgVal = sumVals / i
        outFile.write(u'%s %f\n' % (r, avgVal))

partialValue(5)
```

I already sped it up by going from iterating over the whole `itertools.combinations` generator ([old code](https://github.com/alkamid/quackle/blob/d156695643373073f482d1a3fed5cefd1926ba60/test/partialRacks.py)) to creating a set from the generator and then calculating the multiplier. I could also improve it by creating a generator with **unique** combinations only (so I could skip the set() generation), but I didn't find a built-in function for that.

**How can I optimise the code in terms of speed?** (other hints are welcome as well)

Comment: You could try pypy for a quick win.

Comment: Is this a typo: `for elem in s`? I can't find `s`.

Comment: @U2EF1 Thanks, I'll check it out. However I would be surprised if my code was well optimised, I am a mere amateur.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo sorry, fixed